# Me muestra undefined en el textboxen vez de el valor de ese campo

Tags: php, sql, html5, ajax

Estoy haciendo una web en la que en la página principal consta de un desplegable que según el valor que selecciones se rellena el Imput pero todo el rato me muestra como valor undefined.
Pero si lo muestra en la pagina de la consulta le pongo un echo de la variable del desplegable y el valor que tendría que poner en el textbox si lo muestra pero en la pagina en la que se encuentra el textbox que es donde se tiene que mostrar muestra el UNDEFINED.
¿Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema?

PAGINA PRINCIPAl donded se selecciona el valor del desplegable.

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('conexion.php');
 


function filtrado($datos){
    $datos = trim($datos); 
    $datos = stripslashes($datos); 
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos); 
    return $datos;
}

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
 



?>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 
<head>
    <link href="CSS\style_Modificar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="CSS\Modificar_Datos_Principales.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <title>Modificar Datos Principales</title>
</head>

<body>


  <h1>MODIFICAR DATOS PRINCIPALES</h1>




<div class="Contenido">
  
<form >



<?php 

  $query = 'SELECT * FROM RUCQ_Principal';

  $result = $conexion->query($query);

?>
  <p>Código Interno</p>  
  <select id="producto" onchange="ShowSelected();" name="producto"> 

       <option value="0" > Seleccione:</option> 
    <?php    
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )    
    {
        ?>
    


       <option value="<?php echo $row['Cod_Interno']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['Cod_Interno']; ?></option> 
       
        

        <?php


    }   

    ?>    
    
  </select>
<?php



?> <br>

<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowSelected()
{

var cod = document.getElementById("producto").value;


if(cod == '0'){

alert('Elige una opción');
return false; 

}else{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
clean = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  }else{ 
clean = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  clean.onreadystatechange = function(){ 

  if (clean.readyState  == 4 && clean.status == 200) {  

var respuesta = clean.responseText; 

var jsonjs = (respuesta);



console.log(jsonjs[0].NombreCentroOficial1);



$datos = document.getElementById('NombreCentroOficial').value = jsonjs[0].NombreCentroOficial1;



}

}

clean.open('GET','Consulta_Datos_Principales.php?cod='+cod,true);

clean.send();
 
}
}

</script>



  Nombre Centro Oficial
  <input type="textbox" name="NombreCentroOficial" id="NombreCentroOficial"><br>

  <br> 

  <input type="submit" name="accion" value="Grabar" /> 

</form>


</div>

</body>



</html>
```

PAGINA DE LA CONSULTA.

```html
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$codigo = $_GET['cod']; 

$query = "SELECT NombreCentroOficial FROM RUCQ_Principal WHERE Cod_Interno ='$codigo' ";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query)or die ('Fallo al realizar la consulta');

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{

$datos = array(
                                'NombreCentroOficial1' => $row[0]

);


}

echo json_encode($datos);


?>
```